# Can user type text into a DropDownList in ASP.NET Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a DropDownListFor in my ASP.NET MVC4 Razor layout:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChosenType, new SelectList(Model.Types, Model.ChosenType))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChosenType)
```

Model.Types is a list of possible values.

This works fine, but I want the user to be able to type text into the drop down list as well as being able to select a value - like you can in a WinForms combobox. Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor()` generates a `<select>` element, which only allows selection from the list. You would need to use a jquery plugin.

Comment: take  a look at :http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/01/searchable-dropdown-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds did you ever find out how to achieve this?